# Vectors: dot product projections

Tags: vectors

> Draw a diagram to explain the answer to the following questions.
>
> 1. Is it possible to have $\vec{u}\downarrow\vec{v}=0$?
> 2. Is it possible to have $\vec{u}\downarrow\vec{v}$ undefined?
> 3. Is it possible to have $\vec{u}\downarrow\vec{v}=\vec{v}\downarrow\vec{u}$?
> 4. Explain why $\vec{u}\downarrow(\vec{v}\downarrow\vec{w})=\vec{u}\downarrow\vec{w}$.

these are the questions. i have attempted the first two easily but can't understand the 3 and 4. if you can can you show me how to answer them or provide solutions thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to project one vector onto another? Can you draw it?

Comment: For (c) try $\vec{u}=\vec{v}$; and draw a pic. for (d).

Comment: how to try u=v?

Comment: I'd love to know what $\;\vec u\downarrow \vec u\;$ means...the orthogonal projection of the first one on the second one?

Comment: but i know how to do those my question is for 3 and 4

Comment: ohhhh now i understand you question haha sorry.the notation means: the projection of u onto v.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best to understand that the orthogonal projection of a vector $\vec{a}$ on $\vec{b}$ as the projection of the vector $\vec{a}$ onto the the line continuation of $\vec{b}$. This means that the length of the vector $\vec{v} = \vec{a}\downarrow \vec{b}$ is only defined by the length of $\vec{a}$ and the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. The direction of $\vec{v} = \vec{a}\downarrow \vec{b}$ is the same as $\vec{b}$, with maybe a sign difference.

If we apply that to the question d, you can understand that the vector ($\vec{v} \downarrow \vec{w}$) will be parallel to $\vec{w}$. Now $\vec{u} \downarrow(\vec{v} \downarrow \vec{w})$ will be parallel to $(\vec{v} \downarrow \vec{w})$ and thus to $\vec{w}$. The length of $\vec{u}$ depends only on $\vec{u}$ and the direction of $(\vec{v} \downarrow \vec{w})$, which is the same as $\vec{w}$. What can you conclude?

For your question c, make a drawing of what happens if the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $0$. What if the angle is 90 degrees? What about 180 degrees?